# unable to place upload file in the desired directory

Tags: php, file, upload

i am trying this code below to upload a file in the directory image which is placed inside practice.com in my aamps virtual server. but every time the file is uploaded inside the practice.com directory. how do i place the uploaded file where i want to place them?? currently in  the image folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
$target_dir = "image";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<br>Sorry,".basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])." file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "<br> Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "<br> Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br> Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "<br>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}
?>
</body>
</html
```

>

Comment: Please post your directory tree. It's not clear what you actually want to do.

Comment: my directory tree is: aamps ->www->practice.com->images

Comment: in practice.com all i store all my scripts. and i want to upload the images in image folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constant __FILE__ to have the absolute path of your script then put your directory compared to it. For example : $target_dir = __FILE__ . "/image/";